# Titles as Real Estate

Tags: titles

For a piece that I’m writing, I’m looking for the titles of well known of literature that could double as the heading of a real estate listing. I’ve come up with:

```
As You Like It  
Wind in the Willows  
Animal Farm
```

Can you think of anything better?

Comment: Hi Al Lelopath, welcome to writers. We are a Q/A site, not a forum and part of that means that we expect questions and answers to be of use to more than one person. That means questions that ask us to help generate ideas for your particular project are off topic as they cannot apply to anyone else's work. Sorry to disappoint you on this, but I hope you will stick around and ask any craft-oriented questions you may have. For more information on how things work here, please take the tour: https://writers.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- Middlemarch
- New Grub Street
- Cold Comfort Farm
- 2, The Lighthouse
- Under the Volcano
- Cranford
- Wuthering Heights
- Brighton Rock
- Howards End
- A Room with a View
- Mythago Wood
- Watership Down
- Yarrow
- A Town Like Alice
- The Fountainhead

I generated these fairly quickly by looking at lists of well-known novels and picking out the ones that seemed like place names, the names of houses etc.

As far as I remember, my grandmother's house was actually called, "Cranford".